# menu for menubar icon's menu keeps overlaping the menubar itself

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

[image]

```
 menuBarIconMenu.popUp(positioning: menuBarIconMenu.item(at: 0), at: NSPoint(x: 1842, y: 1414), in: nil)
```

i use this code to make the menu open and yet it wont be behind the menu bar like all the other menus any way to have it go behind the menubar?

---

update1:

```
    statusItem =   NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)

    menuBarMenuIcon = (statusItem?.button)!; menuBarMenuIcon.image = NSImage(named: "MenuBarButton"); menuBarMenuIcon.action = #selector(menuBarMenuClicked); menuBarMenuIcon.sendAction(on:    [.leftMouseUp,.rightMouseUp])
```

this is how i assign the menu

update 2:

this worked 
           statusItem =        NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)
              statusItem?.menu = menuBarIconMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a previous version of one of my apps, I also opened the menu manually by calling the popup function and experience similiar problems. How did you assign the NSMenu? I would suggest that you assign your NSMenu to the menu property of the NSStatusItem. Then you do not have to add code manually to open the menu. DO you have a custom NSView instance assigned to your NSStatusItem?

```
private let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    self.statusItem.menu = self.createMenu()
}

private func createMenu() -> NSMenu
{
    // Close
    let menu = NSMenu()
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(self.quit), keyEquivalent: "q"))

    return menu
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, do you know if theres a way to detect the click on the menu icon, ever since i assigned it to statusitem i cant detect click on it anymore

Comment: In this case you can implement a custom UIView descendant and send a notification (or implement a closure) in the overriden mouseDown func.